# ActiveRecord Subclassing?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

Not sure what the best way to build this with activerecord is. I've looked at STI and polymorphism, but both seem to be less than ideal for this case.

I have three different models which all share similar functionality and some shared attributes. Currently, I have the shared attributes in a separate polymorphic model that each of the three have a has_one association with. This is less than ideal because those attributes are stored in a child object. I would like those attributes to be a part of the model directly.

Any suggestions on how best to accomplish this?

Comment: Some more detail would be nice—how much functionality is shared between your models? Why have you excluded STI already?

Answer (score 4):

You can add your code into a module...

/lib/super_modules/special_power.rb

```
module SuperModules::SpecialPower
  def fly
    puts "I can fly"
  end
end
```

/app/models/model_one.rb

```
class ModelOne < ActiveRecord::Base
  include SuperModules::SpecialPowers
end
```

/app/models/model_two.rb

```
class ModelTwo < ActiveRecord::Base
  include SuperModules::SpecialPowers
end
```

The following would then work:

```
ModelOne.new.fly
ModelTwo.new.fly
```

And you'll probably want to add to config/application.rb:

```
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)
```